# How to get more gargoyle dust

Tags: the-witcher-2

I finished the gargoyle contract in Loc Muine but I didn't farm them to get enough gargoyle dust for the Kinslayer outfit. Is there any way to get more dust? I am willing to hack save file if that's what it takes, by any, I mean any. I am playing to PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can still get them.** In the quest "SECRETS OF LOC MUINE", when you decide to help Cynthia, you'll go through the second guardian (that burning Mordor eye). Then when your answer is incorrect, 3 gargoyles will spawn in there - kill em and the prize is yours.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I think I already cleared this quest. I may check it out, but I didn't play this game for over 6 months

Answer (score 2):

The gargoyles stop spawning after you do the contract so you are at loss there. The only other way I know for getting the dust is by doing the quest [From a Bygone Era](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/From_a_Bygone_Era). Where attacking the operator will spawn Gargoyles. But you need to have started the quest in Act II tho.

Comment: btw the gargoyles that get spawned in that quest are super hard, they hit like trucks.  if that's the only way left to get dust, then he's in for a world of pain.

Comment: Actually the Dark setting is pretty tough so I wanted to get the kinslayer outfit to kill the gargoyles there

Comment: @Eric Hmm i've been looking for a save game editor but the one i found only adds exp and points. And there isn't a mod on the nexus either that helps you. But maybe there is a mod that gives better armor? :p http://witcher.nexusmods.com/